# emacs function won't work, yet there is no error message

Tags: emacs

This is my first attempt at creating a function for Emacs.

I created this simple function:

```
(defun open-init-file ()
  "Opens the ~/.emacs.d/init.el file"
  (find-file user-init-file))
```

I put it in:

```
 ~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

I then ran "eval-buffer".

I got no error message. And yet I can not call this function. If I type M-x and type "open-init-file" I am told that there is no function matching that name.

Even if I put this function in its own buffer, put the cursor at the end, and run eval-last-sexp, this function still is not see as existing in Emacs.

And yet, if I put this in a buffer:

```
(find-file user-init-file)
```

and if I put the cursor at the end of this and then run eval-last-sexp, then this works as I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make and `interactive` function (a.k.a. a command)

```
(defun open-init-file ()
    "Opens the ~/.emacs.d/init.el file"
    (interactive)
    (find-file user-init-file))
```

Answer (score 3):

As yordom mentioned, you need to do:

```
(defun open-init-file ()
    "Opens the ~/.emacs.d/init.el file"
    (interactive)
    (find-file user-init-file))
```

The reason you can't find `open-init-file` when calling `M-x` is that you've defined a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html), not a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html). All commands are functions but not the other way around. :)

Comment: And, if you ever do want to call a plain old, non-`interactive` function, interactively (e.g. to test or explore)? Just use `eval-expression` (bound to `M-:` by default) and enter the lisp syntax for applying a function. e.g. `(open-init-file)`.